# Angular does not update bound property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/5322/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button my-event-directive>Click me</button>
    <div>{{secret}}</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('myEventDirective', function() {
      return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.on('click', function(event){
                scope.$emit('myEvent', {secret: 'aaa'}); 
            });
        }
      }
})

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.secret = 'bbb';
    $scope.$on('myEvent', function(event, data){
        alert('event received!');
        $scope.secret = data.secret;
    });
}
```

After I click the button, the event is received in the controller (alert shows up). However, the `{{secret}}` binding does not update its value. Why?

My event creation is more sophisticated in real code, of course.

Comment: you can always use an `$apply` : http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/5325/

Comment: Works! Please post it as an answer so I can accept it. Worth reading: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: great, glad it helps! (i don't have a time for an answer, sorry:()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Cherinv replied in a comment, when changing a scope attributes outsite the Angular `$apply` method, you have to call it manually. @runTarm also suggested that the event dispatcher should use the `$apply` because listeners are freed from remember it then. So:

```
scope.$emit('myEvent', {secret: 'aaa'});
```

should be changed to:

```
scope.$apply(function() {
    scope.$emit('myEvent', {secret: 'aaa'});
});
```

`$apply` method is described in details in the following article: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: Actually, the `$scope.apply()` should be at the source of the event, I mean after or wrap the `scope.$emit()` instead of inside the listener.

Answer (score 1):

USE $scope.$apply(). NOW the change will be noticed, and the page is updated.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

        myApp.directive('myEventDirective', function() {
              return {
                link: function(scope, element) {
                    element.on('click', function(event){
                        scope.$emit('myEvent', {secret: 'aaa'}); 
                    });
                }
              }
        })

        function MyCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.secret = 'bbb';
            $scope.$on('myEvent', function(event, data){
                alert('event received! secret is ' + data.secret);

                 $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.secret = data.secret;        
                 });
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing binding to happen on object.value rather than value. Maybe it's the case when angular can not trace immutable property change.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button my-event-directive>Click me</button>
    <div>{{data.secret}}</div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('myEventDirective', function() {
      return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.on('click', function(event){
                scope.$emit('myEvent', {secret: 'aaa'}); 
            });
        }
      }
})

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        secret: 'bbb'
    };
    $scope.$on('myEvent', function(event, data){
        alert('event received!');
        $scope.data.secret = data.secret;
    });
}
```

This should work.

P.S. since you always see alert being called that means that you don't need to call scope.$apply to invoke scope digest and the value IS assigned, the problem is that angular can not watch on immutable values (probably)